# Marker latitude to input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, google-maps-api-3

So I am adding markers by click to google maps api v3. For every marker it displays it's coordinates in an info window. Now I want my latitude and longitude to be picked up in an input field (for every marker I add I'm adding a separate form, but somehow it does not work.

What I have:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
    placeMarker(event.latLng);


$('#upload-form').append('<form name="form" method="post" action="saveroute.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">'
                +'<ul id="form-list">' +'<li>' +'<input class="textbox" type="text" name="address" placeholder="Adres"/>'+'</li>'
                +'<li>' +'<input class="textbox" id="lat'+i+'" type="text" name="latitude" placeholder="latitude"/>' +'</li>'
                +'<li>' +'<input class="textbox" id="lng" type="text" name="longitude" placeholder="longitude"/>' +'</li>'
                +'<li>' +'<input class="textbox" type="text" name="description" placeholder="omschrijving"/>' +'</li>'
                +'<li>' +'<input type="file" name="file" id="file" placeholder="Blader naar een afbeelding"/>' +'</li>'+'</ul>'
                +'<button type="submit" class="button-layout">Sla wijzigingen op</button>' +'</form>');

    document.getElementById('lat0').value = location.lat();
    i++;
```

I have put up lat0 as test for the value as the first form that is generated has a field with the id of lat0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no variable `location`, it probably should be:

```
document.getElementById('lat'+i).value = event.latLng.lat();
```